# foreign key not creating in table

Tags: mysql, sql

first table:

```
create table login(
  id int auto_increment, 
  user varchar(20), 
  pass varchar(20), 
  primary key(id)
);
```

first table is created with primary key..

second table:

```
create table check(
  cid int, 
  rid int, 
  usname varchar(20), 
  word varchar(20), 
  FOREIGN KEY(rid) REFERENCES login(id)
);
```

Error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'check
(cid int, rid int, usname varchar(20), word varchar(20), FOREIGN KEY(rid) R' at
line 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't the foreign key.  `check` is a reserved word in MySQL.  So you need to choose another name or escape it:

```
create table `check`(
    cid int,
    rid int,
    usname varchar(20),
    word varchar(20),
    FOREIGN KEY(rid) REFERENCES login(id)
);
```

Ironically, although it is a reserved word, it is not actually used.  Alas, I do wish that MySQL supported `check` constraints.

By the way, [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63e967) is a SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

`check` is a key word in `MySQL`; either surround it with backticks, `, or choose a different name.

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of your table `check`. Check is a reserved word in MySQL